# MySQL Escaping issues

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, quoting

I am doing the following SQL Command:

`INSERT INTO lastlogon( username, lastlogon, datechecked ) 
VALUES ('? Guest_SeEeTooxSafiaH? ? ? ? ? ? ',  '1969-12-31', NOW( ))`

Which PHPMyAdmin states was inserted correctly, no errors arise. However the username value inserted is really:

`? Guest_SeEeTooxSafiaH? ?` not `? Guest_SeEeTooxSafiaH? ? ? ? ? ?` Why is that?

Comment: Is your username field long enough? (I.e is it set as VARCHAR(25) or something, which would truncate the input?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the field is set to VARCHAR(25) ? If so I believe it will disregard anything past the first  25 characters. The fix woudl be set it to VARCHAR(50).

Comment: Nice catch. I didnt originally expect anything over 25 chars.